# The term 'config' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet

Tags: visual-studio-code, solana

I'm not that skilled at visual studio code and programing, but
I'm trying to set up a website for NFTs and I need some code for that.
I need this at the terminal:

```
config set --keypair ~/config/solana/mainnet-beta-test.json
```

but i get this Error:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5bN11.png)

Should I leave this with my poor programing skills?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message is telling you "config" is not recognised as a cmdlet which means it won't be able to run because it doesn't exist.

The reason it is not recognised is because the correct cmd you want to run is probably:

`solana config set --keypair ~/config/solana/mainnet-beta-test.json`